# Cannot bypass registry virtualization

Tags: .net, registry, wow64, registry-virtualization

I have created a subkey in the registry, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp\APIConnector`. When I load this subkey using Visual Studio's Immediate windows while no launched app is running, I can read the subkey.

However, when my application looks for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp\APIConnector`, it cannot find it. It cannot even find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp`. It's as if there's a different

However, when I am running an application in debug mode and it is paused, the exact same code cannot find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp` let alone `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp\APIConnector`.

After a bit of digging around, it looks like I've fallen victim to registry virtualization. So I added a manifest that makes the app require administrator rights (UAC dialog), but registry virtualization is still occurring. Microsoft documentation on the matter asserts that this should not be the case. Help!

Comment: Perhaps you're being affected by Wow64 registry redirection instead (or along with?) registry virtualization:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253.aspx  Windows sure has a lot of smoke and mirrors going on when accessing the registry.

Comment: Yes, WoW64 is the culprit. For some reason the assembly was targeting x86 instead of Any CPU. I changed it to Any CPU and it worked. Turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Steve You really don't want to require admin rights.

Comment: I added admin rights only to check a hunch. As it turns out, it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're being affected by Wow64 registry redirection instead (or along with?) registry virtualization:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253.aspx

Windows sure has a lot of smoke and mirrors going on when accessing the registry.

Comment: Now building as Any CPU (was x86) to take WoW64 out of the picture. Problem solved. Thanks.